# A method besides onPause?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, methods

I have an app that has three activities, the user will be constantly tabbing between these three activities. Right before the user closes the app, my code downloads the current time from the internet and stores it. The problem is that i have my code for downloading the time in the onPause() method. This causes the data to be downloaded over and over each time the user switches activities. I tried using onDestroy() but the download would never start. is there a method that is called when the user minimizes or closes the app altogether instead of one that is called on an activity switch?
Thank you very much, any help is appreciated!

Comment: onStop is not guaranteed to be called

Comment: onStop dosent work because it is called when the activity is switched

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can achieve this using the `Application` class. There we can implement the `ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` to identify when our app goes to the background and based on that result we can perform our required task. Here, a sample code:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application implements ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {

    private Handler mHandler; 

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mHandler = new Handler();
    } 

    ...  

    @Override   
    public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
        Log.i("Activity Resumed", activity.getLocalClassName());

        // cancel scheduled download operation (if any) 
        mHandler.cancelCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    }   

    @Override   
    public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
        Log.i("Activity Paused", activity.getLocalClassName());

        // schedule a download operation after 5 seconds
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
             @Override  
             public void run() {  
                  performDownloadOperation()
             }  
        }, 5000);  
    }   

    ... // other lifecycle callbacks

    private void performDownloadOperation() {
        // perform download operation here
    }

}
```

In the above code, we are basically giving the user [and the system] a grace time of 5 seconds to switch from one activity to another. Otherwise, we note that the app went to background and do our stuff there. So, even if the user switches to a different app for 4 seconds and then come back, we'd still not download the data, which should be fine in most cases.

Note that to use the above class, you need to provide the class reference to the `android:name` property as `android:name=".MyApplication"` under the `<application>` tag in the manifest file.

Comment: i dont know how to directly reply, but what happens if the user minimizes and closes the app within 5 seconds? will the task just not run?

Comment: What do you mean closes? Force stop?

Comment: when the user presses the square to open the recent app drawer (Minimizing the app) and then swipes away the app to (Close) it.

Comment: @Kelton_O I'm about 95% sure (mainly because I couldn't find a well documented viable source) that when the user removes the app from recent apps...the `Application` class would still live

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `Activity::isFinishing()`. This will return false when you (1) launch another activity or when (2) the app is put on background, but it will return true when (3) the back button is pressed or if (4) somebody calls `finish` on the activity.

If it is important to distinguish between (1) and (2), then you can always keep a flag that you can switch every time you launch an activity and reset it in `onPause`.